# Questions regarding Dir VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having a set of files which I want to loop through with the filenames: Budget 2015, Budget 2016, Budget 2017 up to 2022. I loop through them using Dir.

```
Dim OpenWb as workbook
path = Dir("C:\pathtofile\Budget 20??.xlsx") 'Using the ? Dir Wildcard
filepath = "C:\pathtofile\" 'Since Dir returns file name, not the whole path
myHeadings = Split("Januari,Februari,Mars,April,Maj,Juni,Juli,Augusti,September,Oktober,November,December", ",")
j = 0
 Do While Len(path) > 0
    i = 0
    If Dir = "Budget 2014.xlsx" Then
        j=0
    Else
        For i = 0 To UBound(myHeadings)
            Set openWb = Workbooks.Open(filepath & path)
            MsgBox Len(path)
            Set openWs = openWb.Sheets(myHeadings(i))
            If openWs.Range("C34") = 0 Then
                currentWb.Sheets("Indata").Cells(70, i + 27 + 12 * (j + 1)).Value = ""
            Else
                currentWb.Sheets("Indata").Cells(70, i + 27 + 12 * (j + 1)).Value = openWs.Range("C34")
            End If
        Next i
   End if
   path = Dir
   j= j + 1
  Loop
```

The trouble is that in the filepath there's also a file called Budget 2014, which I do not want to loop through because 1) It's not necessary, the values are computed already and 2) Since it screws up my indices in the loop

Updated my code. But using msgBox (path) inside the for i = 0... loop returns "Budget 2014.xlsx" which I did not want to loop, and hence this "messes" with my j subscript.

Comment: I think you are going to have to add an if condition inside the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of the Year method. Something like,

```
Dim OpenWb as workbook, yearNo As Long, filepath As String

filepath = "C:\pathtofile\"
yearNo = Year(Date())

path = Dir("C:\pathtofile\Budget " & yearNo & ".xlsx")

Do While Len(path) > 0
    set OpenWb = Workbooks.open(filepath & path) ' Since Dir only returns file name
    'Doing some things
    yearNo = yearNo + 1
    path = Dir("C:\pathtofile\Budget " & yearNo & ".xlsx")
Loop
```

Comment: Thanks! Haven't tested yet, but it truly was a creative solution which I Think ought to work. I have a follow up question if you have time. I first deduct the value to AA70 (see updated code), where I've added a constant 27 to "reach" column AA to start from. Using Year and my syntax now, would mean that next when yearNo = yearNo+1 is calcuted, that will overwrite my AA70 cell with 2015 values. Is there a way around this? Without needing to update the code next year as well when Year(Date()) will return 2016, and make AA70 have 2016 values?

Comment: Perhaps I've got it! Will have to leave work now, but gonna try to replace j with Year(Date()) mod 2015 and see how it goes tomorrow

Comment: More like `yearNo Mod Year(Date())` ;)

Comment: I'm thinking that yearNo Mod Year(Date()) next year will return 0, and hence the expression will once again AA70 causing the program to overwrite 2015's values next year. Nevertheless, this solution works perfectly! This is my first macro ever, so I'm building it bit by bit, and this solution actually helped me with a piece that I haven't started trying to solve yet (namely what will happen next year). I still have to figure out how to do with December, as values are written in the imported files next year, so I will need to deduct them 2016, but then my program starts 2016 as wel

Comment: Glad to have helped :) Good Lick !

Answer (score 1):

You could also try this:

```
Dim OpenWb as workbook
path = Dir("C:\pathtofile\Budget 20??.xlsx") 'Using the ? Dir Wildcard
filepath = "C:\pathtofile\" 'Since Dir returns file name, not the whole path
myHeadings = Split("Januari,Februari,Mars,April,Maj,Juni,Juli,Augusti,September,Oktober,November,December", ",")
j = 0
 Do While Len(path) > 0
    i = 0
'change here: only execute if it's NOT the file you're NOT after
    If Dir <> "Budget 2014.xlsx" Then
        For i = 0 To UBound(myHeadings)
            Set openWb = Workbooks.Open(filepath & path)
            MsgBox Len(path)
            Set openWs = openWb.Sheets(myHeadings(i))
            If openWs.Range("C34") = 0 Then
                currentWb.Sheets("Indata").Cells(70, i + 27 + 12 * (j + 1)).Value = ""
            Else
                currentWb.Sheets("Indata").Cells(70, i + 27 + 12 * (j + 1)).Value = openWs.Range("C34")
            End If
        Next i
'Change here: only update path & j if you processed the file
       path = Dir
       j= j + 1
   End if
  Loop
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This solution will help me in a later loop which I haven't written here. I had some troubles with the If Dir <> .... loop, but now I see that it can be done in a much simpler way than I expected.

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub M_snb()
 c00 = "C:\pathtofile\"
 sn = Application.GetCustomListContents(4)

 c01 = Dir(c00 & "Budget 20*.xlsx")
 Do While c01 <> ""
  If c01 <> "Budget 2014.xlsx" Then
   With GetObject(c00 & c01)
    For j = 0 To UBound(sn)
     c02 = c02 & "|" & IIf(.Sheets(sn(j)).Range("C34") = 0, "", .Sheets(sn(j)).Range("C34"))
    Next
    .Close 0
   End With
  End If
  c01 = Dir
 Loop

 sp = Split(Mid(c02, 2), "|")
 ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Indata").Cells(70, 51).Resize(, UBound(sp)) = sp
End Sub
```

Comment: +1 since I Believe this will help me get rid of a bunch of if statements using the c02 = c02 & "|" ... solution. Why do you include "|" there? What is sn? Tried to google GetCustomListContents but haven't understood it yet. You never assign sn any value? How does it "understand" what CustomList you're refer to?

Comment: Excel has 4 builtin 'Custom' lists (MS's Humour !). a custonlist ia a one-dimensional array that will be assigned to the variable sn. I include "|" to seperate values in a string, so that the string can be split into a 1-dimensional array (named 'sp') later. You can find a page discussing customlists on the website www.snb-vba.eu

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Will check (I pressume your?) webpage after my meeting. Its nice to see some more advanced techniques for getting the job done, so thanks again!